# All messages sent at once at the end of all iterations django layers Django-channels

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels

I want to send messages to client side by websocket one by one. Instead they are sent at the end of all iterations at once. I use AsyncWebsocketConsumer, so it should be fine. Another important things is that i need to access my consumer method to send data outside of TaskStatusConsumer class, so I use channel groups.
My consumers.py file:

```
class TaskStatusConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        path = [el for el in self.scope['path'].split('/') if el]
        self.id_config = path[-1]
        self.group_name = f"task_{self.id_config}"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        for fr in range(1, 3):
            print(f'start fr {fr}')
            await send_task_status(self.id_config, 'pending', fr)
            print(f'end fr {fr}')
            time.sleep(1)

    async def task_status(self, message):
        print('start task status')

        data = {
            'task_id': message['type'],
            'status': message['status'],
        }
        await self.send(json.dumps(data))
        print('end task status')
```

Function that sends task status to group:

```
async def send_task_status(id_config, status, iteration):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print(f'start send task status')
    await channel_layer.group_send(
        f"task_{id_config}",
        {
            'type': 'task_status',
            'status': status,
            'iteration': iteration
        }
    )
    print(f'end send task status')
```

So at this picture you can see that sending messages to client starts after sending data to group:
[image]